# Allocate memory in a function where the data type is determined by a pass-in value

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I would like to allocate memory for 3D array inside a function.

```
void*** myFunc(int myType){

  double ***p2DArray;

  // Allocate memory
  p2DArray = new double**[HEIGHT];
  for (int i = 0; i < HEIGHT; ++i) {
    p2DArray[i] = new double*[WIDTH];

    for (int j = 0; j < WIDTH; ++j) {
      p2DArray[i][j] = new double[DEPTH];
      for (int k = 0; k < LENGTH; ++k)
          p2DArray[i][j][k] = 0;
    }
  }
  return p2DArray;
}
```

In the code above, double type is created. My question is that how to create different data types according to the `myType` parameter? I don't want to copy the above code twice by the way.

Comment: Unrelated: Use `std::vector<T>` instead of `new T[]`.

Comment: Read about templates. It will actually generate the code multiple times, but at least you'll have to only write it once.

Comment: would the vector<vector<vector<double>>> version be much slower than the pointer version?

Comment: No. Alternatively, calculate your indices to one single number, like `int index(int x, int y, int z) { return x + WIDTH * (y + HEIGHT * depth); }` and use `vector<T>`.

Comment: I would encapsulate the 3d array in a class. Then you can represent it however you like.

Comment: Obligatory link to [Three Star Programmer](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?ThreeStarProgrammer). You really don't want to do this!

Comment: @leemes: Sure about that?  What if he has to traverse each element and there are a relatively large amount of elements in the collection?  Do you realize that each `vector` will use a different backing store for its memory?  Do you understand the effects of cache misses?  Saying "No" is just as wrong as saying "yes".  The answer is "it depends on how you use it".  However, your suggestion about using one large vector and manually calculating indices is right on.

Comment: @EdS. Well, I didn't thought that much about it. However, your argument with the "separate backing stores" also counts for raw arrays. As you can see, he allocates every nested array separately, so a vector can't do it worse, can it? I now see a drawback of one single vector: since it allocates continuous memory to hold all elements, we are allocating maybe (depending on the size) very large memory in one allocation. What if there is no such big continuous space available? Or am I missing something like virtual address space; does it solve this problem?

Comment: @leemes: Yeah, you're definitely right about that; he's allocating each array separately anyway, so it's really no different.  I thought about that after posting and never came back.  Sorry to jump all over you there :)

Comment: @nos: I really doubt it'll matter if it is. (Hint: no.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you find yourself wanting to pass a type to a function in C++ you need to use templates:

```
template <typename T>
T*** func() {
    T*** array;
    array = new T**[HEIGHT];
    ...
    return array
}
```

You can then call this function like so:

```
double*** var = func<double>();
```

When the compiler sees a call to `func<double>()` it will look up the template for `func()` and generate a regular (non-template) function that simply replaces all the `T`'s with `double`.

For this design you should consider using a idiomatic C++ container such as a vector. This provides a number of features that will make your code safer and more readable such as iterators.

One option for vectors is simply to replace your array with `vector<vector<vector<T>>>`. Another option is to use a single `vector<T>` with a size of `WIDTH * HEIGHT * DEPTH`.